# LWUIT : How to Prevent Button change its color in J2ME

Tags: lwuit, nokia-s40

I've created an apps using LWUIT. It use the header bar, like this

[image]

It use the container. Under this header bar container I've created the scroll able list.

The strange part is, if I scroll this list, the color of the button (the menu button and filter button) in header bar changed. And it just happened when I tried the apps in device. When I try using it in emulator it just fine

Here is the code of the button I've created

```
    b_menu.getUnselectedStyle().setBorder(null);
    b_menu.getSelectedStyle().setBorder(null);
    b_menu.getPressedStyle().setBorder(null);
    b_menu.setIcon(ImageUtil.loadImage("/menu.png"));
    b_menu.setRolloverIcon(ImageUtil.loadImage("/menu.png"));
    b_menu.setPressedIcon(ImageUtil.loadImage("/menu.png"));
    b_menu.setName("menu");
    b_menu.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
    b_menu.getStyle().setBgPainter(new LinearGradientPainter(0xcf266a, 0xcf266a, false));
    b_menu.getSelectedStyle().setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    b_menu.getSelectedStyle().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    b_menu.getUnselectedStyle().setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    b_menu.getSelectedStyle().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    b_menu.getSelectedStyle().setBgColor(0xcf266a, false);
    b_menu.getSelectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
    b_menu.getSelectedStyle().setBgPainter(new LinearGradientPainter(0xcf266a, 0xcf266a, false));
    b_menu.getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
    b_menu.getUnselectedStyle().setBgPainter(new LinearGradientPainter(0xcf266a, 0xcf266a, false));
    b_menu.getPressedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
    b_menu.getPressedStyle().setBgPainter(new LinearGradientPainter(0xcf266a, 0xcf266a, false));
```

Have you ever met and solve this problem?

Regards

Giri

Comment: How do you get to hide the native title Bar? I only get to set the app to full screen mode but I lost the top bar too.

Comment: @jmunoz try this

`Display.getInstance().setTouchScreenDevice(true);
Display.getInstance().setCommandBehavior(BACK);`

Comment: That doesn't work, I find a way to show the status bar using `Display.getInstance().setObjectTrait(Display.getInstance().getImplementation(), "nokia.ui.canvas.status_zone", Boolean.TRUE);`

Comment: But I've another question....when you put your app in full screen mode, I suppose that you lost the back native button in all of your interfaces. How do you build this back buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, the answer is I also have to change the unselected style.
Here the code

```
    b_menu.getUnselectedStyle().setBorder(null);
    b_menu.getSelectedStyle().setBorder(null);
    b_menu.getPressedStyle().setBorder(null);

    b_menu.setIcon(ImageUtil.loadImage("/menu.png"));
    b_menu.setRolloverIcon(ImageUtil.loadImage("/menu.png"));
    b_menu.setPressedIcon(ImageUtil.loadImage("/menu.png"));

    b_menu.setName("menu");

    b_menu.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
    b_menu.getStyle().setBgPainter(new LinearGradientPainter(0xcf266a, 0xcf266a, false));

    b_menu.getSelectedStyle().setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    b_menu.getSelectedStyle().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    b_menu.getSelectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
    b_menu.getSelectedStyle().setBgPainter(new LinearGradientPainter(0xcf266a, 0xcf266a, false));

    b_menu.getUnselectedStyle().setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    b_menu.getUnselectedStyle().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    b_menu.getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
    b_menu.getUnselectedStyle().setBgPainter(new LinearGradientPainter(0xcf266a, 0xcf266a, false));

    b_menu.getPressedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
    b_menu.getPressedStyle().setBgPainter(new LinearGradientPainter(0xcf266a, 0xcf266a, false));

    b_menu.addActionListener(this);
    b_menu.repaint();
```

Thanks for viewing this question!

Regards

Giri